# How to implement C2call library in android

Tags: android, audio, videochat

I am trying to implement C2call library that provide's video, audio and Text chat between user's, and i have downloaded the SDK from this [Link](https://www.c2call.com/) after registration.

Before this C2call library i was planning to implement with ooVoo Library but some how i did not understand it fully so i just switch to C2call and trying to implement the same.

The offcial site has given some example with library and i am successfully able to run those example's but when i press Call button, nothing is actually happening.

So i just want to know if someone implemented this same library then please guide me how to overcome this prblem.

I have also read this Below Link,

https://www.c2call.com/component/discussions/6-android-sdk-tutorials/186-need-some-guidelines-on-integrating-the-chat-voip-and-video-call-to-my-app.html

For better understanding i am attaching this screenshot of my screen,

[image]

So when i register and then pressing call button, it is not showing anything just button is clicked and nothing happens.

Comment: +1 this is also nice library, I should learn it too. Thanks

Comment: @Kedarnath, Thank you, if you want to try then read that last link chat, that is very helpful.

Comment: @downvoter's please do care to comment also.

Comment: i am integrating the same c2call functionality but it was showing me the error and didnot allow me to login/registration .Error is this java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.friendcaller.com/app-c2call/C2CallAPIRequest;jsessionid=